# Formatting string with Regex in java, how do I convert captured group to special character?

Tags: java, regex, unicode, special-characters

I have a set of commands that include hidden characters, written in a text file. One by one, they get read and sent a server to execute commands.

Its very important that special characters be formatted properly, however they cannot simply be written in the text file as `"\u0002"`, for example, as that will be interpreted as `"\u0002"`, and not the `<STX>` character that I am looking for.

What I've done, therefore, is to write them in the text file under this format:

```
$'\x02'test$'\x03'
```

and I've written a regex in java to extract the numerical values, as so:

```
"\\$'\\\\x(\w\w)'".
```

(Note the extra escape characters, to escape `$` and `\`)

My question is: How can I grab the hexadecimal characters (`\w\w`), and then convert them to a Unicode character in a string, ideally using String.format?

I know that I'm able to physically grab the characters using `"$1"`, as `"(\w\w)"` is the first and only group in each regex pattern. However, I'm having issues with the conversion. I've tried the following:

```
String.replaceAll("\\$'\\\\x(\w\w)'",
Character.toString((char)Integer.parseInt("$1")));
```

But I'm having issues with the `Integer.parseInt("$1")` part, as `$1` is being interpreted as the string `"$1"`, and not the captured group (for example, 02).

As a quick workaround, I've implemented a workaround for each case that I need, which works.  (example: `String.replace("\\$'\\\\x(02)'", Character.toString((char) (int)0x0002))` ). However, this is obviously terrible form, and not at all effective for parsing any case.

If someone could help me and point me towards documentation / an explanation as to why `$1` is interpreted as `"$1"` and not the captured group, as well as a solution/workaround, it would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

Thank you to nhahtdh below. His answer is correct, although I made one small modification:

```
    static String handleEscape(String input) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$'\\\\x(\\w\\w)'");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(result, Character.toString((char) Integer.valueOf(m.group(1), 16)));
    }

    m.appendTail(result);

    return result.toString();
}
```

I changed `Integer.parseInt(m.group(1))` to `Integer.valueOf(m.group(1), 16)`, to correctly convert any correct string to the associated hexadecimal value.

Comment: Java is not like Perl or other languages, where there is a global variable of sort named `$1` and variable interpolation in string. You are passing `"$1"` into `parseInt`, so it doesn't work. In this case, you would need to write a Pattern Matcher loop to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to manipulate the matched text before replacement, you need to use the low-level API in [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class to perform matching and replacement manually.

```
static String handleEscape(String input) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$'\\\\x(\\w\\w)'");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(result,
            Character.toString((char) Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16)));
    }

    m.appendTail(result);

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Great answer, how would I account for hexadecimal strings containing letters? (for example, 0x00fb)?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Integer.valueOf(m.group(1), 16)